# Specify which foreign key table will be referred to inside of a migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, foreign-keys

I'm developing my Ruby On Rails application that is using PostgreSQL as a database and I've faced a problem.

Here is my `Questions` table (`schema.rb`):

```
create_table "questions", primary_key: "hashid", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.text     "body"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

add_index "questions", ["hashid"], name: "index_questions_on_hashid", unique: true, using: :btree
```

where `hashid` field (string) is being used instead of a default numeric `id` field.

Here's my migration for both `Questions` and `Comments` tables:

```
# Questions migration
class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :questions, id: false do |t|
      t.text :hashid, primary_key: true
      t.string :title
      t.text :body

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :questions, :hashid, unique: true
  end
end


# Comments migration
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.text :body
      t.references :question, foreign_key: :hashid

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I want to relate `Comments` with `Questions` in my application using `belongs_to` and `has_many` relationship accordingly, but the default `t.references :question` is trying to relate by using `id` column from the target table.

Here is the migration error message:

```
== 20160326185658 CreateComments: migrating ===================================
-- create_table(:comments)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "comments" ADD CONSTRAINT "comments_question_id_fk"    FOREIGN KEY ("question_id") REFERENCES "questions"(id)
```

How could I relate by using other than `id` field? In my case it is `hashid`?

Comment: Why do you want to fight Rails conventions and not use the default name `id` for the primary key? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: Because I'm trying to create something like youtube has, it has video ids as random strings, not numeric ids, at least I think so. This is why I've changed default numeric id to random string as id

Comment: You could still name that column `id` even if it contains a random string that is generated by the app. If you chose an other name, you will have to fix many different things: migrations, class primary key definitions, routing, finders...

Comment: Or if there is a way to save records in database using default numeric ids, but rewriting URLs with random strings, I'd better prefer to go in that way. But I don't know really how to achieve that and it is or not a good idea to do that.

Comment: Nevermind. I have figured it out. I just create additional field in my `Question` then I'm assigning random string to field, then in my routing I'm adding routes like so get 'questions/:my_random_string_field', to: 'questions#show'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to still name the primary key column `id` even when the column contains a random generated string.

To create a string `id` column in your database, use a migration like this:

```
create_table :questions, id: false do |t|
  # primary key should not be nil, limit to improve index speed
  t.string :id, limit: 36, primary: true, null: false
  # other columns ...
end
```

In your model, ensure that a `id` is created:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :generate_id

private
  def generate_id
    SecureRandom:uuid
  end
end
```

When you are already in Rails 5 you might just want to use `has_secure_token :id` instead of the `before_validation` call back and the `generate_id` method.